# Ghostscript command not executing from python code while running good from command window

Tags: python, ghostscript

I have a python application which use `subprocess` to run a ghostscript command to convert pdf to png file, like below:

```
pngconvert = ('/usr/bin/gs -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 '
              '-dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dTextAlphaBits=4 '
              '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r150 -sOutputFile="{0}" {1}'.format(pngPath, pdfPath))
subprocess.call(pngconvert, shell=True)
```

However this command didn't run successfully, it only gives the below error message:

```
gs: /apps/asg/packages/ext2py27-234100/g493_linux64/lib/libtiff.so.5: version `LIBTIFF_4.0' not found (required by /lib64/libgs.so.9)
gs: /apps/asg/packages/ext2py27-234100/g493_linux64/lib/libdbus-1.so.3: version `LIBDBUS_1_3' not found (required by /lib64/libavahi-client.so.3)
```

But I am able to run this command successfully on the server terminal.
Not sure what it is wrong, maybe it is missing some libs.

Comment: It could be a Python version issue. Are you sure the same version (and installed modules) is being used in both circumstances?

Comment: Seems your Ghostscript has been built to use system shared libraries, and in the Python environment it cannot find the libtiff shared library. No idea what libdbus is, afaik GS doesn't use that. But as martineau says you need to ensure that Python is using the same environment as the shell. Quite possibly there is some environment variable which is missing when you run under Python. This isn't really a Ghostscript question.